# How can i get the contents of javascript alert message on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

i've been trying to get a message of "javascript alert" on UIWebView.
although it's possible to get the one on Android WebView using by the "onJsAlert" event,
UIWebView doesn't have a kind of the method...
if anyone know the way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Please try to provide more details - what have you tried and how do you know it is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in simple way(ASAIK).
Let's hack it!
Try to re-define your alert function, remember to pass your alert message of the js alert in

***I AM A SPECIAL URL FOR detecting***

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.alert = function(message) { window.location = \"I AM A SPECIAL URL FOR detecting\"; }"];
}
```

And get what you want in the alert url:

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL* url = request.URL;

    // look for our custom action to come through:
    if ( [url.host isEqualToString: @"I AM A SPECIAL URL FOR detecting"] )
    {
        // parsing the url and get the message, assume there is a '='for value, if you are passing multiple value, you might need to do more
        NSString* message = [[[[url query] componentsSeparatedByString: @"="] lastObject] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        // show our alert
        UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"My Custom Title"
                                                     message: message
                                                    delegate: nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
                                           otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alertView show];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i think your solution is interesting!

Comment: I forgot where did i find it. It exists in my dropbox for a long time XD

Comment: I think the best solution lies here. Have a look in this Category https://github.com/wangruofeng/IOS-Categories/blob/master/IOS-Categories/UIKit/UIWebView/UIWebView%2BAlert.m

Comment: Not really, maybe somewhere in stackoverflow